# How should I access Cheetah Template() variable placeholders in an object instance?

Tags: python, enthought, templating-engine, cheetah

I'm trying to set up an object instance that will provide values to the Cheetah3 text templating engine.

This is my text template script...

```py
#filename: py_text_template.py

from traits.api import String, Range
from traits.api import HasTraits

from loguru import logger

from Cheetah.Template import Template

class Info(HasTraits):
    keyword_integer = Range(value=0, low=1, high=60)
    keyword_string = String(value="snack", regex=r"^\w+")

@logger.catch(onerror=lambda _: sys.exit(1))
def generate_text_template():
    myinfo = Info(keyword_integer=10, keyword_string="snack-attack")
    t = Template("On the first $myinfo.keyword_string, my true love")
    print(t)

generate_text_template()
```

I expected to use the `myinfo` instance of the `Info()` class to populate the `Template`, but I get the following error...

```sh
Cheetah.NameMapper.NotFound: cannot find 'myinfo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons I don't yet understand, [`Cheetah`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3) does not follow normal conventions to access object instance attributes and methods.

To fix the problem, I had to replace the `$myinfo.keyword_string` call with `$keyword_string`.  Then I added `searchList=[myinfo]` to the `Template()` call...

```py
myinfo = Info(keyword_integer=10, keyword_string="snack-attack")
t = Template("On the first $keyword_string, my true love",
    searchList=[myinfo])
```

The object instances in `searchList` are searched for the dictionary key, attribute, or method in question.

The complete working [`Cheetah`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3) script was:

```py
#filename: py_text_template.py

from traits.api import String, Range
from traits.api import HasTraits

from loguru import logger

from Cheetah.Template import Template

class Info(HasTraits):
    keyword_integer = Range(value=0, low=1, high=60)
    keyword_string = String(value="snack", regex=r"^\w+")

@logger.catch(onerror=lambda _: sys.exit(1))
def generate_text_template():
    myinfo = Info(keyword_integer=10, keyword_string="snack-attack")
    t = Template("On the first $keyword_string, my true love",
                              # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        searchList=[myinfo])  # <--- put myinfo instance here
    print(t)

generate_text_template()
```

Running this under python3.7 yields the expected results...

```
(py37_test) [mpenning@mudslide fixme]$ python py_text_template.py

On the first snack-attack, my true love
(py37_test) [mpenning@mudslide fixme]$
```

This script requires installing:

- [`Cheetah`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3)
- [`Traits`](https://github.com/enthought/traits)
- [`loguru`](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru)

I'm using:

- `Linux mudslide 5.10.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.70-1 (2021-09-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- Python 3.7.0
- Traits 6.3.2
- loguru 0.5.3
- Cheetah 3.2.6.post1